# How to use onclick with a function expression rather than a declared function?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a button

```
var startButton = $('#startButton').get(0);
```

that I attach the vanilla javascript onclick method to the button and call start on click.

```
startButton.onclick = start;
```

I want to use a function expression but (due to hoisting?) this doesn't call start

```
var start = function() {
  console.log('requesting local stream');
  startButton.disabled = true;
  getUserMedia(constraints, gotStreamSuccess, errorCallback);
}
```

A declared function does

```
function start() {
  console.log('requesting local stream');
  startButton.disabled = true;
  getUserMedia(constraints, gotStreamSuccess, errorCallback);
}
```

How can I write

```
startButton.onclick = start;
```

so that it works with a function expression?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Will, don't forget to mark an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with you that it's a hoisting issue, you'll have to look within your code to hoist it appropriately before setting `startButton.onclick = start;`.

Here's what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) has to say about the syntax:
[image: Syntax for on click]

It specifically mentions that the function can either be declared or expressed. Which, to me, leads again to the hoising, because function declarations are automatically hoisted.

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) for `onclick` uses a function declaration. I changed the example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamback42/4ndrdm5t/) to use a function expression, as you would like to use. With proper hoisting, it is calling the correct method when you click the button.

Comment: Thanks Adam - looks very much like declared is the best way to go on this

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the description of your problem, it seems that you declare (and define) `start` *after* assigning it to `startButton.onclick`. In such case, `startButton.onclick` will indeed be `undefined`.

What is hoisted is the variable itself - your code knows it has been declared, but doesn't yet know its value, as the assignment takes place exactly where you have it in the code. Think of it this way: when you use the `var` keyword, you declare a variable, which, however, is not yet defined. If you happen to immediately assign a value to it, the new value is not visible to the code above the assignment.

Consider the following example:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a);
var a = 2;
var a = 3;
```

Which one of the three values would you expect to be logged in the console? 1, 2 or 3?
You can use `var` for a single identifier as many times as you want (though I would not recommend it); consecutive declarations are simply ignored, only the assignments are taken into account. Because of that, an assignment cannot be hoisted.

Function declarations, however, are finite in some sense, they can be hoisted in their entirety and that is the reason why using a function declaration worked in your case.

To solve the problem, you could indeed use a function declaration, or perform the variable assignment before `startButton.onclick = start;` (and I think you don't really need a variable in this particular case, a function declaration is perfectly suitable for this task).

Note that you could also do:

```
startButton.onclick = function() { // I'm a function expression too!
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event attachment must occur after the creation of the function expression.

Checkout about this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QhLMfTByxTpjihQ0oDI5?p=preview)

```
<button id="click">Click</button>
<button id="click2">Click2</button>

$(function(){

  var startButton = $("#click").get(0);
  var startButton2 = $("#click2").get(0);

  startButton.onclick = clickFunc; // wont work

  var clickFunc = function() {
    alert('click');
  };

  startButton2.onclick = clickFunc; // work
});
```